# How did Tobi control the reanimated jinchuuriki and their tailed beasts?

Tags: naruto

Did he control them with chakra rods, with the reanimation jutsu or with his Sharingan?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**He controlled them using Chakra rods**. Tobi controls his Six Paths using a single black receiver embedded into the left side of each of their chests, which were hidden from view.

Tobi combined the reincarnated bodies of the Jinchuriki with his own "Paths of Pain" Jutsu of the Rinnegan. Similar to the paths of Pain retaining the eyes of the caster, each Jinchuriki had a Rinnegan and Sharingan, allowing them the benefits of the Ocular Jutsu. He also seals their respective tailed beast back into their bodies, which he maintains control of through the Demonic Statue of the Outer Path.

He doesn't however channel the Six Paths Techniques through his "Pains". This is presumably because of the effort required to keep six tailed beasts under his control.

More Reading - [Paths of Pain - Tobi](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Six_Paths_of_Pain#Obito.27s_Paths)

Black Receiver Embedded in the Chest of Yugito Ni.
[image]

Comment: oh!! But couldn't Tobi just control them with his Sharingan genjutsu? Just like he can do with Kurama..and also when Naruto and Kurama became friends and battled the tailed beasts, couldn't he just use his genjutsu to control to nine tails?

Comment: He could. During the Nine-Tails attack on the day Naruto was born, Tobi controlled the Nine-Tails with his Sharingan. But he can't control ALL the Tailed beasts or revive their hosts using Sharingan. Sasuke was able to control all the Tailed Beasts using his Sharingan though.

Comment: oh, so in tobi va naruto..why didn't Tobi control and force out nine tails from Naruto like he did with Kushina?

Comment: @MartianCactus You should check out our chat to discuss theories etc. This is not a forum/Chat thread. If you have any other query, I'd suggest ask a new question. If I've satisfactorily answered your Originl question please "Mark it as correct" and upvote if it helped. http://chat.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MartianCactus Tobi could draw out the Kurama from Kushina not because of his sharingan but because a Jinchuriki's seal weakens during childbirth. Only through force and lots of time can Tobi take out the Tailed Beast. (Like they ACTUALLY do for other JInchuriki). Sharingan can control a Tailed Beast, Rinnegan allows him to channel the powers of Tailed Beasts through the Re-animated Jinchuriki.

Comment: oh!! Now I get it!! The seal has to be weakened!! Thats why he chose the time of childbirth!! So while using sharingan he CAN control tailed beasts but he cant make them break the seal!! BUT Naruto's seal was already undone when they became friends...couldn't Tobi then force out the nine tails?

Answer (score 0):

Tobi used a jutsu, exclusive to rinnegan users, called The Six Path Reanimation Jutsu. With this, he can control their corpses remotely as well as their chakra flow.
In ordre to do this, he used chakra rods, impaled within the corpses which transmit he's order to them.

note that he was using this jutsu on previously reanimated corpses(via edo tensei) as you can tell by there eyes.

One characteristic of this jutsu is that the puppets inherit the puppeteer's Kekkei genkai.